# bash: Interactive scripting with expect_out not working

Tags: bash, expect, interactive

I am trying to run a script interactively with `expect & send` in bash.

The main script prints following to console

```
The available files are...



 1 File_001.bin
 2 File_002.bin
 3 File_003.bin
```

and I want to find index of a specific file say `File_002.bin`, i am writing interactive script like below

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn mainScript.sh;
expect -re "^.*File_002.bin.*$";
set filename $expect_out(0,string);
send_user "The filename is: $filename\n";
```

But its not matching anything! Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: What is the expected output in this case?

Comment: @dgeorgiev: Expecting '2' as output for input File_002.bin